# onUtteranceCompleted does not fires in Android

Tags: android

onUtteranceCompleted does not fires after speak() completed.

This is the code

> HashMap dummyTTSParams
>   = new HashMap(); dummyTTSParams.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
>   "theUtId"); mTts.speak("Hello how are
>   you",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
>   dummyTTSParams);

what is the reason for not calling onUtteranceCompleted(), I mentioned the utterance id "theUtId".

Replay me

Comment: Cann you post your entire code?

Answer (score 1):

And it's very important to call the setOnUtteranceCompletedListener AFTER the TTS initialization.
A good place is the onInit method (the Activity has to implement an OnInitListener interface) when the following condition has been satisfied:

```
status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have added the `setOnUtteranceCompletedListener` listener.

Please have a look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)

Thanks Deepak

Comment: Yes I added setOnUtteranceCompletedListener. I followed the procedure provided in the link.